# Getting the text from a NSTextField and setting it to an already defined String

Tags: macos, cocoa

Im brand new to Cocoa, and im struggling to find the answer and figure it out.

if I have a NSTextField how can I get the value (stringvalue) of that and save it in a predefined string variable, there after display it in the debug using NSLog()?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the stringValue method by NSTextField and save it to a NSString

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSTextField *textField;
}
-(IBAction)displayString:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation

-(IBAction)displayString:(id)sender
{
    NSString *string = [textField stringValue];
    NSLog (@"%@", string);
}

@end
```

Just connect the displayString method to the NSTextField and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that before, the code executes without problems, but the Output in the debug window isnt displayed.

Comment: Did you press enter after inserting the text you want?

Comment: I actually have a button that fires the event, which I have connected to the method. the method does execute, cos i have another NSLog that writes hardcoded text, just for testing.