# Taking a string value from a NSTextField in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, nstextfield

Say a user enters some text `hey` into a NSTextField. I would like to extract this text to a `NSString`, but for some reason, I can't.

I've been trying to find the answer to this question and I've seen many answers on this website saying that you can use `NSString *string = [textField stringValue]` from "[Getting the text from a NSTextField and setting it to an already defined String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591634/getting-the-text-from-a-nstextfield-and-setting-it-to-an-already-defined-string)", but I get the errors `"Expected ',' separator"` between `NSString` and `*string` and `"Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'"` between `textField` and `stringValue`.

How would you store the contents in the NSTextField to a string?

Comment: `NSString *string = [textField stringValue]` is Objective-C. It won't magically compile in a Swift file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the possible duplicate. I didn't find that with my searches, it was the solution I needed. Though, I wanted to store it into a string, not to println() it.